# How to click and turn dial on gauge Charts to get the Points values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I made a chart on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nasri_thamer/0s5nh3nb/). I want to add a click interaction on the dial to transform it into a circle and get the value of thepoint upon button click.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var chart;
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
        },
        // the code is in the JSfiddle
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    events: {
                        click: function (){


                    var point = this.chart.series[0].points[0],newVal;
                            newVal = 200;
                            point.update(newVal);
                            //console.log(point.y);
                            //$(".highcharts-dial").draggable();
                            // highcharts-pane 

                        }
                    }
                }]

            },
            // Add some life
            function (chart) {

                    var point = chart.series[0].points[0], newVal;
                    newVal = point.y;
                    point.update(newVal);
                    console.log(point);

            });

        });
        function selectAngle(chart){
            console.log(chart);
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what isn't working for you? is there an error message? did you try to debug this?

Comment: there is no error . but i want to click to the dial and move it from point to another i don't konw how to do this .. this is my question

Comment: In your example this is how it works, isn't it? When the dial is clicked it points to another value - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is onclick but i want to click the dial and move it and place it where i want because i want to select some points